# Philips 80C552 microcontroller ADC interrupt

Tags: microcontroller, interrupt, adc

I want to create an interrupt service routine for the ADC interrupt that is caused by the ADCI flag when a conversion is finished. However, I can't find the interrupt vector to answer to said interrupt. How do I create the interrupt service routine?

I tried searching for the vector in the interrupt vector table (IVT) but it isn't specified there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you did not specify the document you use. A quick web search revealed [this family overview](https://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/philips/8xc5x2_ov.pdf) at Keil. The interrupt vectors are on page 45, and the vector for the ADC interrupt is 0x0053.

This means, your ISR starts at address 0x0053. With common C compilers the corresponding interrupt number is (0x0053 - 3) / 8 = 10.